# Has this equation appeared before?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request

I want to know if the following equation has appeared in mathematical literature before, or if it has any important significance.

$$\sqrt{\frac{a+b+x}{c}}+\sqrt{\frac{b+c+x}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a+x}{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{x}},$$
where $a,b,c$ are any three fixed positive real and $x$ is the unknown variable.

Comment: Does it arise in any particular context?

Comment: Looks like one of those somewhat but not quite symmetric thingies you see in math contests for gifted high schoolers. Usually those are inequalities though. Can't say, really? What Jack said? How did you arrive at this equation?

Comment: It appeared while I was working with a geometric problem.

Comment: Is it related to spherical geometry ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom: Nope, plane (2D) geometry, though I am more interested in the above algebraic equation.

Comment: You couldn't happen to provide us with a bit more information?  :D

Comment: Does anyone care to solve for $x$?  I can't seem to do it...

Comment: Please provide some context or motivation for this question.

Comment: @SimpleArt: See [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1603501/4781) for the explicit solution for $x$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII I now have many doubts about this having appeared before... Some interesting math. literature the OP is reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This provides the explicit polynomial in $x$ (for those curious), though I'm not aware if the equation has appeared in the mathematical literature. We get rid of the square roots by multiplying out the $8$ sign changes,

$$\prod^8 \left(\sqrt{\frac{a+b+x}{c}}\pm\sqrt{\frac{b+c+x}{a}}\pm\sqrt{\frac{a+c+x}{b}}\pm\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{x}}\right)=0$$

then collecting powers of $x$. It turns out the $8$th-deg equation factors into a linear (cubed), a quadratic, and a cubic. For simplicity, let,

$$\begin{aligned}
p &= a+b+c\\
q &= ab+ac+bc\\
r &= abc
\end{aligned}$$

Then,

$$(p+x)^3=0\tag1$$

$$r^2 - 2 q r x + (q^2 - 4 p r) x^2 = 0\tag2$$

$$p r^2 + r (-2 p q + 9 r) x + (p q^2 - 4 p^2 r + 6 q r) x^2 + (q^2 - 4 p r) x^3 = 0\tag3$$

> **Example:**

Let $a,b,c = 1,2,4$, then

$$(7+x)^3=0\\
-16 + 56 x + 7 x^2 = 0\\ 
-112 + 248 x - 119 x^2 + 7 x^3 = 0$$

The roots of the quadratic solve,

$$\sqrt{\frac{a+b+x}{c}}\pm\sqrt{\frac{b+c+x}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+c+x}{b}}-\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{x}}=0$$

while a root of the cubic solves,

$$\sqrt{\frac{a+b+x}{c}}-\sqrt{\frac{b+c+x}{a}}-\sqrt{\frac{a+c+x}{b}}+\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{x}}=0$$

and two others, while the linear root takes care of the remaining three sign changes.

Comment: Wow!, thanks. How did you factor the degree 8 polynomial? Did you use brute force or a computer program, or did you use any clever technique?

Comment: @pritam: _Mathematica_ saves a lot of time when doing calculations. Originally, I got a horrible mess, but the fact that $a,b,c$ are symmetric was my clue to use the _elementary symmetric polynomials_ and simplify the factors of the octic.  :)

Comment: @pritam: By the way, the analogous equation, $$\sqrt{v_1}+\sqrt{v_2}+\sqrt{v_3}+\sqrt{v_4}+\sqrt{v_5} = 0$$ where the $v_i$ now uses $a,b,c,d,x$ resolves into a $16$-deg eqn with a **non-solvable** Galois group. Thus, the $a,b,c,x$ case is rather special.

Comment: Reference for the above fact? Is it mathematica again :)? and what is the Galois group for our case (which should be solvable)?

Comment: @pritam: Our friend _Mathematica_ again. :)  For the case $a,b,c,x$, as the octic factors, then one is actually dealing with a [transitive group](http://galoisdb.math.upb.de/) of deg $2$ (with order 2) and deg $3$ (with order 6).

Comment: I have accepted your answer, although I haven't verified it in Mathematica yet; by hand I can only verify the special case $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 0):

I edit this answer to explicit the degree of the resulting polynomial having $x$ as a root (*I wonder about the exact origin of this strange unknown x. Explanation is tedious and it will be presented abbreviated as possible, just to have the degree of the polynomial without using algebraic number theory which is not so useful without knowing the particular values of $a,b,c$*).

First at all one has  $$\sqrt{\frac{b+c+x}{a}}+\sqrt{\frac{c+a+x}{b}}=\sqrt{\frac{a+b+c}{x}}-\sqrt{\frac{a+b+x}{c}}$$
Squared twice and, for convenience, make the following notations:
$$\begin {cases}A=\frac{a+b+x}{c}+\frac{a+c+x}{b}\\B=\frac{a+b+c}{x}+\frac{b+c+x}{a}\\M=(\frac{a+b+x}{c})(\frac{a+c+x}{b})\\N=(\frac{a+b+x}{x})(\frac{b+c+x}{a})\\C=\frac{B-A}{2}\\D=\frac{B^2-A^2+4N-4M}{4}\end{cases}$$ 
One has the linear system
$$\begin{cases}\sqrt M+\sqrt N=C\\ A\sqrt M+B\sqrt N=D\end{cases}\qquad(*)$$
So, for instance $$\sqrt M=\frac {CB-D}{B-A}\Rightarrow M=\left(\frac{CB-D}{B-A}\right)^2\qquad(**)$$
Thus a rational resultant is 
$$\left(\frac{a+b+x}{c}\right)\left(\frac{a+c+x}{b}\right)\left(B-A\right)^2=\left(B^2+A^2+4M-2AB-4N\right)^2\qquad (***) $$
Explaining $(***)$ with values of $a, b, c, x$ gives
$$G(x,a,b,c)-(H(x,a,b,c))^2=0$$ with 
$$G(x,a,b,c)=bc(ax)^2(x^2+A_1x+A_2)(A_3+x)^2(abc-A_4x)^2$$
$$H(x,a,b,c)=\{bc(x^2+(b+c)x+A_5)\}^2+\{ax((b+c)x+A_6)\}^2-2abcx\{(b+c)x+A_7)(x^2+(b+c)x+A_8)+2(ax^2+A_9x-A_{10})\}$$
where $$\begin{cases}A_1=2a+b+c\\ A_2=a^2+ab+ac+bc\\ A_3=a+b+c\\ A_4=ab+ac-bc\\ A_5=a(a+b+c)\\  A_6=b(a+b)+c(a+c)\\  A_7=A_6\\  A_8=A_5\\A_9=a^2+ac-bc\\ A_{10}=b^2c+bc^2\end{cases}$$
Therefore one can see at first sight that degree of $G$ is $8$ and so is for the degree of $H^2$ so that the degree of the resultant equation could be in general $8$.

►However it could be maybe for particular values of $a,b,c$ that the coefficients of $x^8$ in $G$ and $H^2$ be equal so the degree were less than $8$; this happen if 
$$bca^2(ab+ac-bc)^2=[b^2c^2+4a^2+a^2(b+c)^2(1-4b^2c^2)]^2$$ which seems to be possible for some values of $a,b,c$.

►On the other hand, solving also in $(*)$ for $N$, one gets $$N=\left(\frac{D-AC}{B-A}\right)^2$$ we can, in general, by multiplication and subtraction of the coefficients of $x^8$, eliminate the degree $8$ so this degree can be reduced.

►With the two polynomials giving by the system $(*)$, we can eliminate the unknown $x$ and find a relation $F(a,b,c)=0$ in order both polynomials have common roots (this can be made by Sylvester’ method, for instance, which would give a large zero determinant for $F(a,b,c)$

I stop here. I have wanted to help @pritam, assuming he is really interested in the rare equation proposed (I don’t discard some typo in my answer).

Comment: The deg $8$ has linear, quadratic, and cubic factors. Kindly see my answer.

Comment: I'll see it after. Now I have no time. Thank you.

Comment: Hi dear friend Tito Piezas III: $a,b,c$ are arbitrary positive so I doubt the resolving polynomial never be irreducible over $\mathbb Q(a,b,c)$.; also you have , when $a=b=c$ the equation $3x^2+6ax\pm a^2=0$. (I am wrong?). Regards.

Comment: If you have access to _Mathematica_, then you can easily retrace what I did and factor the octic. Besides, I gave a random example to show that the formulas work.

Comment: What about my three signs ►? I fear then, according what you say, that my calculations lead to useless identities, maybe. I always prefer not to see the amazing and extraordinary internet calculators to answer questions. I know that is something wrong position, but I like working "by hand". Thank you very much for your message, dear friend.